# How to bind a component view the same way as a property-binding without using ngComponentOutlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been working on an Angular project that requires to use multiple detail component views depending on the data provided. I was able to achieve this using ngComponentOutlet with Injector object. However, the rendering is too slow whenever I'm retrieving data from the server.

What I'm looking for is a way to pass a component view as a value without using ngComponentOutlet unless otherwise stated. This will prevent me from binding multiple views in the projecting component.

Here's what my detail view classes for each component may look like:

```
@Injectable()
class CustomerViewDetail {
  name: string | undefined;
  more: any;
}

@Injectable()
class CartViewDetail {
  name: string | undefined;
  more: any;
}

@Injectable()
class OrderViewDetail {
  name: string | undefined;
  more: any;
}

@Injectable()
class AboutViewDetail {
  name: string | undefined;
  more: any;
}

@Injectable()
class ProductViewDetail {
  name: string | undefined;
  more: any;
}
```

Here are the components I expect to project their views:

```
@Component({
  template: `<h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>`,
})
class Customer {
  constructor(public item: CustomerViewDetail) {}
}

@Component({})
class About {
  constructor(public item: AboutViewDetail) {}
}

@Component({})
class Product {
  constructor(public item: ProductViewDetail) {}
}

@Component({})
class Order {
  constructor(public item: OrderViewDetail) {}
}

@Component({})
class Cart {
  constructor(public item: CartViewDetail) {}
}
```

Here, I'm using them as values:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-projector',
  template: `<ng-container *ngFor='let item of dataList'>
    <ng-container
      *ngComponentOutlet="
        item.componentView;
        injector: getInjector(item.data);
        content: []
      "
    ></ng-container>
    <ng-content select="[componentDetailView]"></ng-content>
  </ng-container>`,
})
class ComponentProjector {
  constructor(public injector: Injector) {}

  getInjector(
    item:
      | CustomerViewDetail
      | ProductViewDetail
      | OrderViewDetail
      | CartViewDetail
      | AboutViewDetail
  ) {
    return Injector.create({
      providers: [{ provide: typeof item, useValue: item }],
      parent: this.injector,
    });
  }

  @Input()dataList = [];
}
```

And this is the hosting component:

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  template: `
    <component-projector [dataList]="dataList">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let data of dataList" componentDetailView>
        {{ data | json }}
      </ng-container>
    </component-projector>
  `,
})
class HostingComponent {
  dataList: any[] = [
    {
      data: CustomerViewDetail,
      id: 'Customer',
      componentView: Customer,
    },
    {
      data: AboutViewDetail,
      id: 'About',
      componentView: About,
    },
    {
      data: ProductViewDetail,
      id: 'Products',
      componentView: Product,
    },
    {
      data: OrderViewDetail,
      id: 'Orders',
      componentView: Order,
    },
    {
      data: CartViewDetail,
      id: 'Cart',
      componentView: Cart,
    },

];
}
```